# How to stop python.exe window from closing when running Fabric

Tags: python

*Preface*: Using Windows 7, Python 2.7, [Fabric 1.2.2](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html)

I am trying to run Fabric script on windows, from [a simple tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/tutorial.html). I have my "fabfile.py" with a simple hello world program, and then I execute:

```
fab hello
```

However, every time a python.exe window pops up and immediately closes! I have no way of actually seeing what the error is. Is there any way to keep it open?

This is a different question from the others, as I have no way of "holding" the window open - because "fab" is not my script, but something that is installed on the system. It fails even BEFORE it gets to my file.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use python with or without the command shell. This is useful when you are running a GUI program and you do not want a associated terminal to open up.

This is possible if the python executable you are referring to is associated with pythonw.exe which is used to surpress the terminal.

Fab is a python script. It is quite possible that it is associated with this.

- See: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

Try running - "path/to/python.exe path/to/fab hello". This if it works, then that is certainly the case.

On a unix machine, fab script looks like this:

```
#!/path/to/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'Fabric==1.0.0','console_scripts','fab'
__requires__ = 'Fabric==1.0.0'
import sys    
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('Fabric==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
)
```

Comment: Running python on fabric
`>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\fabric`
gives me:
`C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\fabric'`